# App ID Prefix at apple developer

Tags: ios, xcode6, code-signing

I am trying to figure out where we are getting the App ID Prefixes while creating a new App ID at Apple Developer. While checking Apple Developer under the Apple Developer Enterprise program, it is showing 4 App ID prefixes, but I am only able to figure out the source of Team ID. I am not sure about others, though.

I have looked into various Apple documents but I am still confused about where we are getting them and how we can remove them.

It would be great if any one can help me to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

There's a reason you have an app prefix ([Apple technical note describing why linked here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2311/_index.html)), so it looks like you can change the prefixes to match if you want to have shareable UIPasteboards.